# 'ascii_lowercase' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm attempting to try a simple command on the command line,

```
dict(zip(ascii_lowercase, range(4)))
```

expecting to get

```
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}
```

but I keep getting the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "`<stdin>`", line 1, in `<module>`
>
> NameError: name 'ascii_lowercase' is not defined

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you imported it correctly? `from string import ascii_lowercase`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ascii_lowercase` is a value provided by the `string` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase). To use it unqualified, you must have previously imported it via:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
```

Comment: @wogsland: In general, if you encounter a problem like this, and you don't think it's a typo, [search the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/search.html) (or the whole internet) for the name, odds are you just missed a necessary import.

Comment: FYI - my question has been downvoted, so I may delete it. Still appreciate your help though!

Comment: @wogsland Woot? Don't delete because it's downvoted. It should be deleted only when it adds no value to SO. I'd say keep it. Someone might commit the same error and will google search to end up on your question. He might upvote it.

Comment: @MYGz In my experience the herd mentality seems to prevail on SO, but I shall conduct an experiment here and see...

Comment: @MYGz Apparently I cannot delete a question with answers anymore, so I guess I'll have to suffer the herd continuing to downvote it...

Answer (score 0):

Why zip with range when you can enumerate?

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

print {b:a for a,b in enumerate(ascii_lowercase[:4])}
```

Output:

```
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}
```

Comment: Well, if we're trying to optimize, this is 2.7, so use a `dict` comprehension and avoid temporary `list`s, unnecessary generator and function call overhead, etc.: `{b: a for a, b in enumerate(ascii_lowercase[:4])}`

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks :D. Sometimes the Pythonic solution doesnt comes so naturally. Unless you are Dutch. like the Zen Of Python says.

Answer (score -1):

You can also import the `string` module, and apply your own function using `string.ascii_lowercase`:

#### Test

```
import string

print(dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, range(4))))
```

#### Output

```
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}
```